# IOC using AutoFac for internal class

Tags: class, inversion-of-control, autofac, internal

I have an internal class which is internal visible to a service Factory. It is also inheriting an public interface.

When I want to use its functionality in my application, I am declaring object for the interface and getting it instantiated for the particular class through service factory.

Now we are using MVC and I want to create IOC for this class in my one of the controller. 
This class being internal, I can not register this in global.ascx

For example when I am writing 
builder.RegisterType().As().InstancePerHttpRequest() ;
The CommonSvc being internal, it is throwing compile time error as Services.CommonSvc' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Please advise

Comment: Why don't you make the class public?

Comment: One approach is that classes shouldn't be public so people don't use them when they should be using the interface. This approach is like Ninject, where each project has to reference Ninject, but then each project controls its own binding.

Answer (score 6):

Your options:

1. Make `CommonSvc` public
2. Annotate your assembly with an [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) to make internal types visible to the calling assembly.
3. Instead of registering `CommonSvc` directly, use `RegisterAssemblyTypes()` to register it by convention. For example:

```cs
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(SomeOtherTypeInTheSameAssembly).Assembly)
           .Where(t => typeof(SomeInterface).IsAssignableFrom(t))
           .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```